# Jmeter protobuf testing. Could not read Protobuf message

Tags: java, jmeter, protocol-buffers

I am testing one project via protobuf protocol and using HTTP Request Sampler. The target appserver is also written on Java.
There is a problem with errors in reponses:

> "Could not read Protobuf message: Protocol message contained an
>   invalid tag (zero).; nested exception is
>   com.google.protobuf.InvalidProtocolBufferException: Protocol message
>   contained an invalid tag (zero)"

The case is that it is happening not in 100% requests. When i used **HttpClient4** it was about 30-40% of failed requests. After i changed it to **HttpClient3.1** error rate decreased down to **~10%** which is also not a good deal.

To send a protobuf message I am using variable ${data} in Bodydata tab of HttpSampler. And in BeanShell preProcessor i do the next:

```
(import and non-necessary stuff were ommited)
MapViewport mv = MapRequest.MapViewport.newBuilder().setMaxX(mc.getX()+15).setMaxY(mc.getY()+15).setMinX(mc.getX()-15).setMinY(mc.getY()-15).build();

byte[] data = mv.toByteArray();
vars.put("data", new String(data));
```

Also I tryed to to use different encoding like a **new String(data,"UTF-8")** anso on.

If to look on Request tab if View Result Tree I can say that all failed messages   contain "?" symbol:

[image][image]

Seems like some weird symbols should not be sent, but ~10% of requests after saving a byte array to String contain them.

Comment: So you're converting a binary stream to String to save as a var - which can be fraught with issues depending on the encoding. It is also system dependent and behavior can change. Moreover when you're `${data}`, you're sending a string, which for some binary data is inserting `?` The first workaround that comes to mind is to write the binary stream to file and use the file path as variable in bodydata. But that would cause a lot of File I/O for high volume. Hmm.. this is a bit of a thinker.

Comment: Alternatively you can assemble your own HTTP request and send it from a beanshell sampler instead of using a HTTP sampler. Wonder if the `HTTP Raw Request` from jmeter-plugins would be useful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm fairly convinced your issue is that you're losing some non-printable characters while converting from binary stream to String and then back. I'm thinking of two possible workarounds:

1. Write the binary data to a file instead of saving to string, and then use the filename as variable in the HTTP sampler, in the body from file section
2. Use a beanshell sampler, and construct your own HTTPClient object and POST request, with the binary data in body and fire it yourself instead of using the HTTP sampler

I don't like the first option because of all the additional file I/O. I do not like the second option because measuring response time will now include all the request assembly you're doing in beanshell - so you'll have to pick the one that bothers you less I guess.

Let me know if you want me to write up some code examples for either case.

Edit: For beanshell HTTP call using HttpClient 4:

```
import org.apache.http.HttpEntity;
import org.apache.http.HttpHeaders;
import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.client.ClientProtocolException;
import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost;
import org.apache.http.entity.ByteArrayEntity;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;

byte[] data = null;
//...assign protobuf binary buffer to data...

HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
HttpPost post = new HttpPost("http://127.0.0.1");
HttpEntity entity = new ByteArrayEntity(data);
post.setEntity(entity);
post.setHeader(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_TYPE, "application/octet-stream");
HttpResponse response=null;
try {
    response = client.execute(post);
} catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
} catch (IOException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
}

ResponseCode = response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode().toString();
//if some assert is true then
Issuccess = true;
ResponseMessage="Some Response Message";
```

This is untested against a protobuf end point, let me know how it works out for you.

Comment: Perhaps base64-encoding the data would help? (FWIW, the problem is definitely due to trying to shove non-textual binary data into `String`s -- that never works.)

Comment: @RaGe could you provide some example of HTTPClient in Beanshell ?

Comment: update with some code. I tested it against a regular http endpoint but not against a protobuf endpoint, don't have one handy.

Answer (score -1):

On high loads Beanshell interpreter can be the cause of unexpected behaviour as it has some performance problems. Try switching to [JSR223 PreProcessor](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_PreProcessor) and use [groovy](http://www.groovy-lang.org/) as a language. Groovy scripting engine implements [Compilable](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html#jsr223) interface hence given you follow some simple rules you can achieve best performance and your problem can go away.

See [Beanshell vs JSR223 vs Java JMeter Scripting: The Performance-Off You've Been Waiting For!](https://blazemeter.com/blog/beanshell-vs-jsr223-vs-java-jmeter-scripting-its-performance) article for groovy engine installation instructions, scripting best practices and Beanshell versus Groovy benchmark.

Comment: Have tryed JSR223 PreProcessor the result is absolutely the same :(

Comment: @v0devil your issue is that you're converting from binary data to strings and back, and losing some non-printable characters in the conversion. Beanshell stability isn't the problem.

Comment: @RaGe yep seems like. I did not get your comment about using HTTP Raw Request - that`s will be the same way, no ?

Comment: I haven't used the Raw Request sampler, but I was hoping it would allow more control on what you can put into the POST body