# Jmeter. JSR223+Grovy 2.4.5 sampler response times degradation

Tags: jmeter, beanshell, jsr223

(question is continue from [Jmeter protobuf testing. Could not read Protobuf message](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33753119))
I am testing application via Protobuf protocol. Initially i used HTTP sampler but was a problem with saving binary data to a string.
Solution was to use Beanshell sampler with HTTPClient and POST request with the binary data in body:

```
byte[] data = null;
//...assign protobuf binary buffer to data...

HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
HttpPost post = new HttpPost("http://127.0.0.1");
HttpEntity entity = new ByteArrayEntity(data);
post.setEntity(entity);
post.setHeader(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_TYPE, "application/octet-stream");
HttpResponse response=null;
try {
    response = client.execute(post);
} catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
} catch (IOException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
}

ResponseCode = response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode().toString();
//if some assert is true then
Issuccess = true;
ResponseMessage="Some Response Message";
```

Because i try to provide the high load with several thousands of concurent users  i started to use JSR223+Grovy sampler instead of Beanshell samler (was influenced by this article https://blazemeter.com/blog/beanshell-vs-jsr223-vs-java-jmeter-scripting-its-performance)

During the test all JSR223 sampler have a strong growth of response times:
[image: JSR223 sampler response times during first 5 minutes]

Then a created a new testplan and just replaced all JSR223 with Beanshell samplers (without reset option). The picture was ok (graph in the same scale):

[image: Beanshell sampler response times during first 5 minutes]

So how to recognize what is wrong with JSR223 or maybe to fix it. And another questiong why everybody recomend to use JST223+Grovy when it provides kind of these problems?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ah ok, in this article was recomendation to use Compilation cache key. I have not seen it. Now everything is ok.